# Erro Expected SSH_FXP_VERSION ao conectar via php com phpseclib

Tags: php, ssh

Ao conectar em alguns equipamentos estou obtendo essa mensagem:

> Expected SSH_FXP_VERSION e o comando não é executado.

Estou utilizando php com `phpseclib`.

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro pode ser causado por vários motivos, dentre eles:

1. Implantação não padrão do protocolo SSH no roteador;
2. Constantes do phpseclib não definidas corretamente (principalmente em algumas alterações no mesmo);
3. Erro de recebimento do pacote de autenticação (problema de rede);

Tente olhar com calma a implantação da biblioteca, o bloco que retorna o erro é esse:

```
$response = $this->_get_sftp_packet();
if ($this->packet_type != NET_SFTP_VERSION) {
    user_error('Expected SSH_FXP_VERSION');
    return false;
}
```

pode ser encontrado em [Net/SFTP.php](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php)